# How to restrict in Jenkins users from viewing users information like: id, name etc

Tags: jenkins, centos

I have configured Jenkins on centos 7.

Being administrator, I have created few users and gave them permissions to their projects like: build, read etc. 
I have used a Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy. Its working but I'm facing the following problem:

If any user clicks on people information (button on left is dashboard) then any user can view all the other users ids, name etc. I want to block this from happening and I can't find a solution to this problem.

Can it be a configuration problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution using the [Role Strategy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin).

I'm using this plugin for our Jenkins server and it's really useful to define permissions.

On my staging Jenkins, I've create 2 users:

- A full admin
- A viewer

I've created 2 roles with the plugin:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Next, I assign the roles to the relevant users:

[image]

[image]

The viewer role only have a global read access + build on the jobs.

If I open a session with the admin one, I can see all the people:

[image]

With the viewer user, I don't see anything:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

If you want to assign some permissions on a specific project, you can create project roles (in the Manage Roles section):

[image]

You can filter the projects with a regular expression:

```
job(.*)postcommit
```

Next, in the Assign Roles section, you just have to assign the relevant project role to the relevant user.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks my problem is solved but still one new problem, how can I assign a viewer to view a specific project. I have not seen any option is config of project ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, if this solution works for you, don't forget to vote :)

Comment: Hello, I have done that setup, but I still can see People information with readonly permissions. Has something changed during this time? I've found a an issue raised since a long time ago that never was fixed: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-18884?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true
Do you know some other way to restrict People page? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudioSaavedra Sorry for my late answer, we are using the same configuration since 3 years I think we no changes.